# Authenticate for new APIM REST APIs?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager old [store/publisher APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Store+APIs), I can login and get a cookie for authentication. But in [new APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/store/#!/operations#ApisAPIApi#apisGet) I can't find a login API. In docs I can see it uses a (OAuth) token.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer aa0ddec1ac656744234477f20fafcb0d" http://127.0.0.1:9763/api/am/store/v0.9/apis
```

But I don't see a way to get it. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an OAuth2 application using DCR API. Docs can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/store/index.html#guide). Then call to token API and get an access token.